Django custom user admin not reflected in admin site
I am new to django and going through legacy django project where Custom user admin is configured with following:
app1/admin.py

from .models import User

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    """Define admin model for custom User model with no email field."""

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number',
                                         'type_of_user', 'timezone', 'deleted', 'is_supervisor',
                                         'supervisor', 'role')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined',
                                           'created_date')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('username',)

Also in app1.models.py, where CustomUser is further inherit from AbstractBaseUser.
class User(CustomUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, db_index=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, db_index=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    is_supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    license = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    type_of_user = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_OF_USER, default=1, db_index=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    timezone = TimeZoneField(choices=[(tz, tz) for tz in pytz.all_timezones])
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    load_id = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    approval_status = models.IntegerField(choices=APPROVAL_STATUS, null=True, blank=True)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    last_alert_sent_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey("common.Role", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             null=True, blank=True)    

In settings.py:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app1.User'
There's no admin.py in main_app folder.
The problem here is that the User model is not associated with this particular UserAdmin.
Even if I remove this @admin.register(User) class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin): in admin.py the users are still displayed.
Here's the admin interface for Users.

As you see, the fields are also different from what is defined here:
list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
Why is the custom user admin not working in this case?

Have you ran the django migrations after creating the custom user model?
You would be able add the updated models in database schema only after running the migrations.
Commands to migrate the changes to database schema:
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations


I just restored the sql dump, so I guess that won't be necessary?
